# App Engine monitoring dashboard for multiple apps

Tags: google-app-engine, monitoring, dashboard

I run a number of webapps on Google App Engine. I'm looking for a monitoring
dashboard that shows me metrics from multiple App Engine apps at the same time,
on the same page. Ideally it should also pull metrics from Google's APIs
directly, as opposed to requiring me to instrument my code.

So far, everything I've seen only shows a single app at a time:
[Google Cloud Console](http://console.developers.google.com/appengine/),
Google's [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.cloudconsole),
[Stackdriver](http://www.stackdriver.com/),
[Datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/),
etc.
[HawkEye](https://portal.appscale.com/) looks like it might work, but it hasn't
managed to actually pull up any of my apps' metrics yet.

I tried making a simple HTML page with iframes for each of my apps' monitoring
dashboards, but Google blocks that with `X-Frame-Options`. :/

(Also, these are side projects, so I'm willing to pay a little if necessary,
e.g. $10s/mo, but not more.)

Comment: Better suited for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: what kind of metricts, btw?

Comment: @DanCornilescu agreed, i've [migrated it to ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/734037/app-engine-monitoring-dashboard-for-multiple-apps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now merge accounts in Stackdriver monitoring and create any combination of dashboards

https://app.google.stackdriver.com/accounts
[image]